# Multiple types on arrow function parameters throwing ts error: ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, arrow-functions

I am passing an arrow function inside a config ( object )

```
const config:IConfig = {
    render: (item:string)=>item
}
```

My parameter item can be `string` | `string[]`. So the interface I am using is

```
interface IConfig  {
    render: (item:string|string[])=>string
}
```

But with the above code the line `render: (item:string)=>item` throws an error saying

```
 Types of parameters 'item' and 'item' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

I have tried another interface which is working perfectly fine

```
interface IWorkingConfig {
    render: ((item:string )=>string) | ((item: string[])=>string)
}
```

The only difference is instead of having multiple `types` to parameters, I am passing multiple functions.

**Problem with the above interface syntax**

I need to duplicate the entire function just to change the type of parameter. This is building up a lot of repetitive code.

> Runnable [Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFsFcBsBcEsAO0CmpYE9EoM7oPaiICGATseCrCqegBan4Du8AdgOag2OkBQb1UgDNiAYzQBJAML5WQ+J1ABvXqDWhSKVgBMaALlAAKeNXB6csUm3YAfC1Y4BtALoBKALwA+e9d4BfXl4QUHhwZBRKVlhiBFleUVkLUAS5BT1pWXlOd2VVdU0dfSMTCPNLaw9PEvB-QKCwAFom5pbWtvaOuuCoOCRUUCFIVlFY1jxWfFh6RhYOLlIefiiaEXFQCQB1fFIAa2sZVM4VdQ0tXVIDQ2NTModOSp8OV1AbI2vS0Ef2Fwfyp9rAsFQuFItFRvFElMmNs9hwDll0ltdvtMgp3Md8mciu8zF8fl5qgA6ABW+DYhgA5A0Ka5akA) for above mentioned snippets

Comment: your code snippet doesn't contain any code

Comment: also where do you call the `IConfig `